# What does the condition: '*s1 = *s2' do exactly?

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop

Consider following code:

```
void concatenate(char *s1, char *s2){
    while(*s1 != '\0'){
       s1++;
    }
    for (; *s1 = *s2; s1++, s2++){  
    }   
}
```

In the above function, in for-loop the condition `*s1 = *s2`  is checked every time. How can this be possible?
It also assigns the value pointed by `s2` to the value pointed by `s1` and what is checked then for the loop to continue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instruction `"*s1 = *s2` copies value at address by `s2` to value at address by `s1` and then that value becomes break condition in for loop, So loop runs till `\0` found which is equal to `0`. (Note, the ASCII value of `\0` nul char is zero = `false` in C).

```
for (; *s1 = *s2  ; s1++, s2++)
           ^           ^ 
           |           | 
        assign         increments both 
        *s2 to *s1,     
       then break condition = *s1  (updated value at *s1 that is \0 at the end)
```

This is how you copy string from `s2` to `s1`, and also checks whether string termination symbol came `\0` (=`0` as ASCII value).

Answer (score 2):

I've reformatted the code so that it looks better and it's easier to explain, I've added explanation in the form of comments.

I also added parentheses around the assignment as suggested by the compiler (when compiling with warnings enabled).

```
void concatenate(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    /* s1 initially points to the first char of the s1 array,
     * this increments it until it's reached the end */
    while(*s1 != '\0')
        s1++;


    /* the initialisation part is empty as there's no initial assignment
     * the test condition tests if assignment evaluates to positive, 
     * when null terminator is reached it will evaluate to negative 
     * which will signal the end of the loop
     * the afterthought increments both pointers
     * */
    for (; (*s1 = *s2)  ; s1++, s2++)
        ;
}
```

Note that this function is pretty unsafe as in the case of no null-terminator the pointers may be incremented to point to non-valid memory.

It also doesn't check if `s1` is big enough to hold `s2`.

Answer (score 1):

The value being assigned is what is checked.  The value is assigned, and then if that value was zero (signalling the end of the string) the loop exits.

In C, an assignment operation is also an expression, with the value of the expression being the value that's being assigned.

Answer (score 1):

`s1` and `s2` are both pointers. `*s1` is the *value* at the location the pointer points to. Since you move both pointers in the `for` loop, you are comparing different `values` every time you hit that condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is programme to concatenate two string.With first while loop pointer reches upto end of string 's1'. Now in for loop each char from `s2` is assigned to `s1`.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop runs till it have its condition expression true(means not zero). When the end of the string s2 is reached, ie '\0' which is same as 0(false), it is assigned to *s1 and it is zero, So now the condition expression is false and so exit from for loop